# Python with Javascript VM security

Tags: javascript, python, security, dictionary, reduce

I am thinking about making a simple map reduce application that is written in python, I am not looking to make this some super public project or anything just using it for learning about the challenges behind a platform like map reduce. I thinking of using a javascript vm with the mangment of the cluster in python, the reason is I want it to be easy for someone to be able to submit code to be processed and means i dont need to eval python code. What i want to avoid is abusive javascript, not in the idea of long running but to avoid it breaking out of the javascript vm or having access to the linux host that the python runs on. I have seen a Python V8, SpiderMonkey and a few other but not sure if they include that feature.

Question:
When it comes keeping the embeded javascript vm away from touching the operating system what are my options, and are these options limited or not needed in some of the javascript vm's that can be used with python

Comment: And the question is? For conceptual questions, maybe you should prefer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: added and how do you move a questions or is a copy paste job?

Comment: Moderators can migrate it, I think, but I'm not sure about that.